# Getting multiple words in an ArrayList<String> from a String message using Stream

Tags: java, list, java-stream

> **Question:** Is there an effective and efficient way to return a list of Strings that show up in a message given a list of words using Stream/Parallel Stream?

Let's say I have 'ArrayList banWords' which contains a list of words players cannot say. Now let's assume 'message' represents the message a player types. How would I check to see if 'message' contains any words in 'banWords' and if so, return all the words that appear in 'message' using Stream?

I'm asking this since I'm not very familiar with Stream and haven't found a suitable question that has been asked in the past. Currently, the code loops through every word in 'banWords' and checks if 'message' contains that word. If so, it gets added to a separate ArrayList.

```
for (String word: banWords)
    if (message.contains(word))
        // Adds word to a separate arraylist
```

However, I'm trying to see if there's a way I can use Stream or Parallel Stream to return the words. This is the closest I've found

```
if (banWords.parallelstream().anyMatch(message::contains) {
    // Adds the word to another list using banWords.parallelstream().filter(message::contains).findAny().get()
}
```

However, that only returns the last word that appears in banWords. For example, if banWords contains 'hello' and 'hey' and the message is 'hello hey,' instead of adding "hello" and "hey" as two separate words, it just adds "hey."

Any ideas on how I can effectively get a list of words in message? At this point, I'm looking for the most effective or quickest way to do this so if you have another way that **doesn't** use Streams, I would be happy to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose of you have a String `ArrayList banWords` then create stream using that string, and use `filter` to filter strings that contains `banWords`

```
List<String> list = Stream.of("ArrayList banWords").filter(s->s.contains("banWords"))
                                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can create stream with multiple strings also

```
List<String> list = Stream.of("ArrayList banWords","Set banWords", "map").filter(s->s.contains("banWords"))
                                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So this is how you need to do

```
List<String> list = word.stream().
                        .filter(s->message.contains(s))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is there a method that gets each word and replaces it automatically with another word? I would also love to learn more about parallel and parallelstream. Any ideas where I can begin? I currently have an Iterator<String> going, but I'm looking to see if there's another way

Answer (score 1):

`message.stream().filter(s -> bannedWordSet.contains(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Something to note, it's important to use a set for your list of banned words instead of a list. It'll be much more efficient.

Comment: Nothing pops up whenever I begin typing "message.stream()" in IntelliJ...

Comment: If I use a set, which is more efficient with its .contains method, is there any point in using parallel stream then?

Comment: @FrankW. Yes they're different concepts. Despite that, assuming that you're not dealing with thousands of words at a time there's no reason to use a parallel stream. On small data sets parallelizing it doesn't do anything. A set is more efficient than a list because it's constant time contains instead of O(n)

Comment: I read that Set uses 5.5 times as much memory as Lists. If the goal is to conserve memory, wouldn't that mean I should switch over to ArrayLists? I'm coding something for my friend and I'm just trying to get it right...

Comment: In general memory is much less important than speed. But like I said for small cases it won't matter much. In general yes it's an optimization of memory v. speed, however in 99% of cases you'll choose speed

Answer (score 1):

you can collect to list after `filter()`

```
List foundWords = banWords.parallelstream().filter(message::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
```